# How to draw a rectangle around a set of candles in a Custom Indicator?

Tags: mql4

Say I have two candles that satisfy a property, I want to draw a rectangle around them, like in the following picture under, in a Custom Indicator.

What should I do?

The [**`SetIndexStyle()`**](https://docs.mql4.com/customind/setindexstyle) does not seem to have this option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Doable  <sup>( but not via any of the Custom Indicator line-formatting services )</sup>

Given the said above,
the rectangle placement & formatting ought be programmed explicitly, best using a principal, re-useable GUI-object handling function template idea like this:

```
void UpdateRECTANGLE( int      const     anObjIdNUM,
                      datetime const       fromTIME,
                      datetime const         toTIME,
                      double   const      fromPRICE,
                      double   const        toPRICE,
                      color    const         aCOLOR = clrDarkBlue,
                      int      const aLineTHICKNESS = 2,
                      int      const      aLineTYPE = STYLE_SOLID,
                      ){
#define aMainWINDOW   0

     string                         anInterimObjNAME = StringFormat( "GUI_RECTANGLE[%6d]", anObjIdNUM );
     if (  ObjectFind(              anInterimObjNAME ) == aMainWINDOW )
           ObjectDelete(            anInterimObjNAME );
     else: ObjectCreate( ChartID(), anInterimObjNAME, OBJ_RECTANGLE, 0, fromTIME, fromPRICE,
                                                                          toTIME,   toPRICE
                                                                          );         
     ObjectSet( anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_COLOR,         aCOLOR );
     ObjectSet( anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_BACK,          True );
     ObjectSet( anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_WIDTH,         aLineTHICKNESS );
     ObjectSet( anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_STYLE,         aLineTYPE );
     ObjectSet( anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_SELECTABLE,    GUI_SELECTABLE ); // ----------------------------------------- AVOIDS GUI interactions
     ObjectSet( anInterimObjNAME, OBJPROP_SELECTED,      False );
     return;
}
```

---

> **Epilogue:**
>   one may also be aware, the Custom Indicator is a bit risky piece of code to place any heavy-lifting processing, convoluted TimeSeries re-counting, external AI/ML-code transactions handling into, because, all, **yes all** MetaTrader Terminal graphs all share, **yes, indeed, all SHARE** a single thread ( and one can imagine, what a blocking / long hanging processing may cause to all dependent processes, if all ( again, **YES, ALL** ) have to wait, till a single, shared, blocking thread gets enough CPU-clocks to finish processing of all the queue of requests all other graphs' experts and their dependent Custom Indicator calls have placed in front of our call request.
> **Does not sound risky to your ears?** Believe me, **it is...** A lot!